# why I can't use x.unique() in numpy, however, x.sum() or x.mean() works?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning numpy, however, I don't understand that, for example:

```
import numpy as np
ints = np.array([3,3,3,2,2,1,1,4,4])

ints.unique() # this won't work
np.unique(ints) # this works
```

however, some function works both ways

```
ints.sum()
np.sum(ints)
```

And I was reading numpy documents, what's the different between `attributes` vs `methods`? `arributes` will return something as well as `methods`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique` unlike `sum` is a **free function** *only* and not a class (instance to be precise) **method**. The difference between the two is

```
obj.foo()   # instance method, obj is implicitly passed to foo()
foo(obj)    # free function,   obj is explicity passed to foo()
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python) for some explanation on different variants of methods. In NumPy, this is mainly a design decision, I believe, however there are certain reasons for some functions to be a free function. One reason that comes to mind, is that unlike in other technical languages (such as MATLAB), numpy arrays can be structured or unstructured and can be flexible in terms of containing objects of different types, for example

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])        # structured array
b = np.array([[1,2],[3,4,5]])      # unstructured array
c = np.array([[1,2],["abc",True]]) # unstructured array with flexible data type
```

In such scenarios, having to make every function/method an instance method, would lead to confusing behaviour. Even the `sum` function behaves differently with structured and unstructured arrays

```
In [18]: a.sum() # sums all elements of the array
Out[18]: 10
In [19]: b.sum() # concatenates all elements of the array
Out[19]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In contrast, some functions like `unique` have a much narrower scope in terms of their applications. For example `unique` only works for structured arrays/buffers of uniform data type and operates on the flattened (1D dimensional) version of the arrays.

`attributes` of numpy arrays typically tell you about the underlying data type, shape, dimensionality, memory layout/strides and data ownership of the array, for instance:

```
In [20]: a=np.random.rand(3,4)
In [21]: a.flags
Out[21]: 
    C_CONTIGUOUS : True
    F_CONTIGUOUS : False
    OWNDATA : True
    WRITEABLE : True
    ALIGNED : True
    UPDATEIFCOPY : False

In [22]: a.shape
Out[22]: (3, 4)

In [23]: a.dtype
Out[23]: dtype('float64')
```

are all `attributes` and not array methods per say, in other words they are properties.

Comment: I've never noticed that function like sum will behave differently on different array. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your `a` is a regular 2d numeric array (dtype int), `b` is an object dtype array, containing 2 lists (of different length).  `np.sum(b)` and `b.sum()` use `list` add, which is a concatenate.  `c` is a (2,2) array of dtype string.  `sum` or `add.reduce` has not been implemented for that dtype.  If `c` was created with length 2 and 3 lists, it too would be object dtype, and concatenate the lists. `[1, 2, 'abc', True, None]`.

Comment: numpy object dtype arrays have a MATLAB counterpart - cell.  They also are like Python lists.  In numpy `structured array` usually refers to something else, an array with a compound `dtype` (earlier known as record arrays).

Answer (score 1):

`np.sum` is a function that takes an array, or anything that can be turned into an array, and applies it's `sum` method.  See `np.source(np.sum)` for details.

`arr.sum` is a method of the `arr` array. For a `ndarray` is compiled code.  A subclassed array may have a different `sum` method.

Most of the cases where the are like-named functions and methods, a relationship like this holds.

Look at the source for `np.unique` to see a different design.  One difference that comes to mind is that `unique` only works with 1d arrays, or with a flattened array.  It's not as general purpose a method like `sum` or `mean`.

Some of these differences follow a pattern, or are explained, others are probably more the result of a development history.  Often it is easier to add new functionality by writing a 'stand-alone' function, rather than adding a method to an existing class.  The method is more closely integrated with the class.

To get into more details you'll have to spend time reading the development archives.  For roughly that last 5 years, much of that can found by searching the respective `github` repository and its `issues`.